# WSO2 4.5.0 "&" characters turns into "&amp;"

Tags: xml, wso2, wso2-esb

I am reading a **.txt** in **WSO2 4.5.0** with

```
<parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/plain; charset=windows-1252</parameter>
```

that contains the "&" character.

After I transform the message to XML the `&` character turns into `&amp;`, how can I go through the file and replace all existing `&amp;` back to `&`?

Answer (score 0):

Open the XML file using your preferred XML library.

Use the library's API to access either the attribute value or the text value of the text node (depending on where the data appears).

Changing `&amp;` to `&` in the XML file will render the XML invalid and cause parses to reject it. (Since `&amp;` is how you express `&` in XML).

Comment: After the XML transformation the message is then transformed to a Fixed Length file and that is the file that should have the "&" character and not the "&amp;" character

Comment: @RamtinBehrouz — So do the "reading the XML" part of the transformation with an XML parser as described in the answer.